# SQL Query to Remove Portion of text in whole table

Tags: sql

I have Comment Table which has CommentText filed in it. now I want to remove text inside this [quote] and [/quote]. in this case I can reduce the size of table by removing Quote texts and keep the main comment. in addition some times we have nested quote which would be something like this:

```
**[quote name="sAe!D"]
    some text here
    [quote name="John"]
        Another nested text here

        [quote name="User2"]
            Another nested text here
        [/quote]
    [/quote]
[/quote]
Here would be the Text of comment owner which should be Kept.**
```

I need to remove all except "Here would be the Text of comment owner which should be Kept."

Comment: What RDMS are you using? SQLServer, MySQL, Oracle or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. You could try using some text manipulation on the comment text column, removing everything after "[quote" and adding it to the result of reversing the comment text and performing the same operation (to remove everything after "[/quote]", but backwards). This will leave only the bits outside your tags:

```
DECLARE @RemoveFrom VARCHAR(50) = '[quote'
DECLARE @RemoveTo VARCHAR(50) = '[/quote]'

-- Take all text before the text we remove
SELECT LEFT(CommentText,CHARINDEX(@RemoveFrom,CommentText,1)-1)
-- add all text after the text we remove (which is the reverse of above, with the result reversed)
    + REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(ComentText),CHARINDEX(REVERSE(@RemoveTo),REVERSE(CommentText),1)-1))
FROM Comment_Table
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, I will test and allows you to know about the result.